# CMake Error: Error processing file: cmake\scripts\install_deps.cmake WINDOWS

Tags: installation

I am trying to set up my ethereum c++ client on Windows.

I already ran this command line

`git clone --recursive https://github.com/ethereum/cpp-ethereum.git`
which successfully worked. 
Now, in the second step, I opened my command prompt, and I went into the directory that contains the scripts folder in the cpp-ethereum directory, and typed `install_deps.bat`
where I found this error

CMake Error: Error processing file: cmake\scripts\install_deps.cmake

What am I doing wrong? I never used cmake before, so I have no clue..

Comment: @AchalaDissanayake how can I tell?

Comment: @AchalaDissanayake okay, I did do that.  I got a new error though. `ERROR FILE:    https://build.ethdev.com/builds/windows-precompiled/boost-1.55.0`
`ERROR CODE:    0x80072efd - A connection with the server could not be establish`
`ERROR CONTEXT: 0x00000005 - The error occurred while the remote file was being`

Comment: sorry, I think its not gonna that way, try downloading it from [here](https://github.com/ethereum/cpp-ethereum/releases)